# Creating theme using typescript in React

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript

I am just starting a React project and is required to create a css using typescript by referring to the color palette diagram below. When creating the theme using createMuiTheme, I noticed that there were multiple possible conditions for each color set, which means that I have to create multiple theme for each of the set ? Since I am new to React and TypeScript, I am quite confused on implementing different opacity and text color on different color set, thus would like to get a solution to simplify the whole thing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [Styled-components](https://medium.com/@rossbulat/creating-themes-in-react-with-styled-components-6fce744b4e54) for styling. Learn ts with react [how to use it](https://javascriptplayground.com/react-typescript/). Hope this will help you